# What is the difference between crc32 and crc32b?

Tags: php

Apparently the PHP function [`hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) can be called with, among others, the values `crc32` and `crc32b` as the `$algo` parameter? What is the difference between them?

Comment: There are a couple of users explaining it here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-file.php#104836

Comment: google got me this-- shld help http://www.pal-blog.de/entwicklung/perl/2012/crc32-vs-crc32b.html

Answer (score 8):

Two different algorithms. CRC32b is an implementation of the consistency algorithm defined [here](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-I.363.5-199608-I/en), whereas CRC32 is the frame check sequence defined [here](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-V.42/en). They're different things, though the differences are not often big.

One way to check this:

```
<?php
echo hash("crc32", __FILE__)."<br/>";
echo hash("crc32b", __FILE__); ?>
```

Due to their similarity, the starting hex values will be relatively similar.

Comment: Is there a reason to choose one over the other?

Comment: @user2045006: Nope. They only differ in their implementation details and historical uses. One works with streams, the other with frames. For the large majority of cases, this can be assumed to be equivalent in performance.

Answer (score 5):

As per answer by apm on php.net: "I have verified that the output of the "crc32" is the ITU I.363.5 algorithm (a.k.a. AAL5 CRC - popularised by BZIP2 but also used in ATM transmissions - the algorithm is the same as that in POSIX 1003.2-1992 in Cksum but that stuffs the size into the CRC at the end for extra measure). -- The crc32b is the 32-bit Frame Check Sequence of ITU V.42 (used in Ethernet and popularised by PKZip). The output from this CRC is popularised in Intel little endian format and would produce cbf43926 on the same file."

The full comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-file.php#104836

Answer (score 1):

> The difference between crc32 and crc32b is explained on mhash man page. crc32 is the one used on ethernet, while crc32b is the one used on zip, png... They differ on the table used.

[quote taken from php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-file.php#85672)