# php hash('crc32') and crc32() return different value

Tags: php, hash, crc32

i want to ask about PHP crc32 hashing.
i'm tried using `hash('md5','value')` and `md5('value')` its return same output.

> output : 2063c1608d6e0baf80249c42e2be5804

but when i'm try to use `hash('crc32','value')` and `crc32('value')` its return different output.

> hash() output : e0a39b72
>
> crc32() output : 494360628

anyone know why it can return a different output?

thanks :)

Comment: That's because one is a hash and one calculates the polynomial of a string...

Comment: i see, thanks :)
so, how to make the output same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `hash("crc32b", $str)` will return the same string as `str_pad(dechex(crc32($str)), 8, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT)`.

See [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crc32.php) and also about difference between [crc32 and crc32b](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15861058/what-is-the-difference-between-crc32-and-crc32b)

Comment: Instead of `str_pad(..., 8, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT)` you can do `sprintf('%08s', ...)`

Answer (score 4):

There are minor differences between them, first of all `crc32()` uses the hashing algorithm `crc32b` and `crc32()` returns an integer unlike `hash()` that returns a hexadecimal value.

```
$str = 'testing';

$hex = hash('crc32b',$str); // e8f35a06
$dec = crc32($str);         // 3908262406

echo dechex($dec) == $hex; // true, both value e8f35a06
echo hexdec($hex) == $dec; // true, both value 3908262406
```

Keep in mind that the values differ on 32 and 64 bit environments.

Answer (score 3):

What PHP calls `crc32(...)` or `hash("crc32b", ...)` (one returning an integer, the other a string) is the standard PKZip/ITU-T V.42 CRC-32. What PHP calls `hash("crc32", ...)`, oddly using the same name as the incompatible PHP `crc32()` function, is different, and is the BZIP2 CRC-32.